# Remove all characters before specific character in array

Tags: c, arrays

Say I had the following code:

```
char url[63] = {'\0'};
scanf("%s", url);
```

And the user is asked to submit a url. I need to remove the characters that are typically at the beginnings of url such as http://, ftp://, etc...

I could check for the existence of "://" in the character array using a for loop like so:

```
 int i;
 for (i=0;i<strlen(url);i++) {
     if (url[i] == ':' && url[i+1] == '/' && url[i+2] == "/") {
        // Super cool code here... 
     }
 }
```

But say I wanted to delete the :// and everything that came before it? How would I accomplish that? So that if the user entered:

> http://www.google.com

The output would be:

> www.google.com

And a similar result if ftp:// were used.

Comment: You could try to access a part of memory that you have not allocated.  You only need to go to stlin(url)-2

Comment: The only thing I could think of was assigning the characters to \0 but that obviously wouldn't work as it eliminates everything that comes after as well..

Comment: If the idea of copying the characters you want into another string never occurred to you, then you stopped thinking way too soon (which is one of the points of that link).

Comment: `char *str = "some string"; int pos = 5; char *cut = strdup(str+pos);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

```
int i;
 for (i=0;i<strlen(url) - 2;i++) {
     if (url[i] == ':' && url[i+1] == '/' && url[i+2] == '/') {
        // Super cool code here... 
        return &url[i+3];  
     }
 }
```

To create a copy:

```
char* getInteresting(char* url)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0;i<strlen(url) - 2;i++) {
        if (url[i] == ':' && url[i+1] == '/' && url[i+2] == '/') {
            // Super cool code here... 
            int len = strlen(url) - (i+2);
            char* copy = (char*)malloc(len + 1);
            strcpy(copy, url + i + 3);
            return copy;  
        }
    }
}
```

Plus: a lot more checking through the error cases!

Comment: don't you mean return &url[i+3] ?

Comment: say I wanted to set the modified url[] array equal to a new array...how would that work?

Comment: Thank you! I finally understand how to do this. Really appreciate your help. :D

Answer (score 1):

Usually the easiest way to do this sort of thing in C is to not actually change the original array at all, but instead to create another `char *` pointer to the first part of the string you actually care about.  So....

```
 int i;
 char *interesting_stuff;
 for (i=0;i<strlen(url);i++) {
     if (url[i] == ':' && url[i+1] == '/' && url[i+2] == "/") {
        interesting_stuff = url + i + 3;
     }
 }
```

and then go on to do things with `interesting_stuff` and leave `url` alone.  (Be aware that it's a pointer into the same array, so if you overwrite `url`, you will lose `interesting_stuff` too.)

BTW, the bounds on that `for` loop will get you in trouble.  You potentially look two characters past the end of the string, and my modification makes that problem a bit worse.  You need to check the length of the string first and be sure that you don't go past the point in the string where `://` followed by some useful data could be found.  In other words, you want to constrain your loop to `strlen(url) - 4` except be careful if `url` is shorter than 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* ssc = strstr(url, "//:");
if (ssc)
{
   const char* withoutProtocol = ssc + 3;
   // do something with withoutProtocol
}
```